# How to orchestrate a clustered Quartz job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, distributed-computing, orchestration

Say I have a `BackendApp` that deploys as a WAR and is deployed to multiple nodes. I deploy it to multiple nodes for high availability. The app uses Quartz to schedule certain jobs being kicked off. Let's say one of these jobs should only be ran once a day.

If I have the app deployed to 5 nodes, it will get ran 5 times a day, once on each node.

Do any mechanisms exist to orchestrate certain jobs things that should only run once in a distributed/clustered environment, and not by each app instance in the cluster?

I did find [this article](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11) but it seems to be a solution that is limited to one node:

> Never run clustering on separate machines, unless their clocks are synchronized using some form of time-sync service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JDBC store and set clustered to true, make sure all the nodes are on the same database and make sure all the machine have a time-sync service.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX

Comment: Thanks @ebtokyo - can you give an example of what you mean by a "time sync service"? Is this a linux thing? Is this a library I could use? Thanks again!

Comment: I am not an expert but you need to see with your sys admin. It is a server/network configuration on the OS level. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897 / http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-ntp.html